# How to use pymongo.monitoring in a Flask project with mongoengine

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, mongoengine

I am trying to add some monitoring to a simple REST web service with flask and mongoengine and have come across what I think is a lack of understanding on my part of how imports and mongoengine is working in flask applications.
I'm following pymongo's documentation on monitoring : https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/3.7.2/api/pymongo/monitoring.html

I defined the following CommandListener in a separate file:

```
import logging
from pymongo import monitoring

log = logging.getLogger('my_logger')


class CommandLogger(monitoring.CommandListener):
    def started(self, event):
        log.debug("Command {0.command_name} with request id "
                   "{0.request_id} started on server "
                   "{0.connection_id}".format(event))

monitoring.register(CommandLogger())
```

I made an application_builder.py file to create my flask App, code looks something like this:

```
from flask_restful import Api
from flask import Flask

from command_logger import CommandLogger # <----
from db import initialize_db
from routes import initialize_routes

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)
    initialize_db(app)
    initialize_routes(api)
    return app
```

The monitoring only seems to works if I import : `CommandLogger` in application_builder.py. I'd like to understand what is going on here, how does the import affect the monitoring registration?

Also I'd like to extract `monitoring.register(CommandLogger())` as a function and call it at a latter stage in my code something like `def register(): monitoring.register(CommandLogger())`
But this doesn't seem to work, "registration' only works when it is in the same file as the `CommandLogger` class...

Comment: Please reference relevant driver documentation from the question.

Comment: @D. SM thanks for your comment, I'm working based off of this documentation [link](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/3.7.2/api/pymongo/monitoring.html)

Comment: So you are asking why your code is run only when you import it? Because python only executes code in imported modules.

Comment: For your second question add actual result and expected result to the question.

Comment: Your comments just reminded me that you need ` if __name__ == "__main__":` to prevent bits of code from being executed during import. Not quite used to that yet.
And that basically answers half my problem, which was in fact really trivial... Thanks

Comment: Feel free to write the answer here and accept it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

From the MongoEngine's [doc](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/logging-monitoring.html), it seems important that the listener gets registered before connecting mongoengine

> To use pymongo.monitoring with MongoEngine, you need to make sure that
> you are registering the listeners before establishing the database
> connection (i.e calling connect)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I'm just initializing/registering it the same way as I did other modules to avoid circular imports.

```py
# admin/logger.py

import logging
from pymongo import monitoring

log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


class CommandLogger(monitoring.CommandListener):

    # def methods... 

class ServerLogger(monitoring.ServerListener):
    
    # def methods

class HeartbeatLogger(monitoring.ServerHeartbeatListener):
   
   # def methods

def initialize_logger():
    monitoring.register(CommandLogger())
    monitoring.register(ServerLogger())
    monitoring.register(HeartbeatLogger())
    monitoring.register(TopologyLogger())
```

```py
# /app.py

from flask import Flask

from admin.toolbar import initialize_debugtoolbar
from admin.admin import initialize_admin
from admin.views import initialize_views
from admin.logger import initialize_logger
from database.db import initialize_db
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.errors import errors


app = Flask(__name__)

# imports requiring app
from resources.routes import initialize_routes

api = Api(app, errors=errors)

# Logger before db
initialize_logger()

# Database and Routes
initialize_db(app)
initialize_routes(api)

# Admin and Development
initialize_admin(app)
initialize_views()
initialize_debugtoolbar(app)
```

```py
# /run.py

from app import app

app.run(debug=True)
```

then in any module...

```py
from admin.logger import log
from db.models import User

# inside some class/view/queryset or however your objects are written...
log.info('Saving an item through MongoEngine...')
User(name='Foo').save()
```

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to integrate Flask DebuggerToolbar's Logging panel with the monitoring messages from these listeners...